# how can I can running status from my table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a below table which has multiple rows with same executionid and different status. How can I get the row which status is running, rows will be exclude if executionid associated with both running and completed status?

Below image is the sample data :

[image]

Expected result should be:
[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (I'm not sure the answer will run on both.)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: I'm using Postgresql.

Comment: @DebasishHalder will you always have 3 status values or more ?

Comment: @trillion most of the time status value have 3, also some cases 4(pause status also there).

Comment: @DebasishHalder does the solution below works for you ?

Comment: @DebasishHalder also you have 4 status in total or there are more as well, the point is to understand how many distinct status will you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using String_AGG() to get all the status per execution id into one list
- Joining that list to the original data and then filtering out the results using NOT LIKE operator, if there are cases that are completed and running then they are not selected

```
with all_status as (
Select

execution_id,
STRING_AGG (status,', ') as all_status_per_id
from [table]
)

Select 
data.*,
all_status.all_status_per_id
from [table] as data
left join all_status 
on data.execution_id = all_status.execution_id
where (all_status.all_status_per_id LIKE '%running%' AND all_status.all_status_per_id NOT LIKE '%completed%')
AND status = 'running'
```

Comment: 2 rows are coming as a result where exectionid(122) and status(started and running) .

Comment: @DebasishHalder can you try again

Comment: i have made the adjustments

Answer (score 0):

Simple select:

```
select * 
  from your_table
 where status = 'running';
```

This is about as basic SQL statement that tou can get. I suggest you get a SQL text, and try a few tutorials.

Comment: If I run your qeury it will return 2 rows where executionid 121 and 122, but I need only executionid 122 which status is running. executionid 121 has completed and running both. I want a row whose status is running which does not completed.